# Is there any alternative approach other than deploying python flask application in Google app engine flex environment?

Tags: python, flask, dialogflow-es

We have a dialog flow chatbot (deployed via Google Assistant) with fulfillment written in python flask and deployed in Google cloud App Engine flex environment.

Google Actions --> Google Dialogflow --> Webhook fulfillment in Python Flask App (deployed in Google cloud app)

Since we are in the development stage the cost of the service is very high and we couldn't afford it for a long term.

We tried with Google app engine standard environment, it is getting deployed in http url which we cannot use as dialogflow fulfillment.

We also tried to deploy our app in a Virtual Private Server (Hostinger VPS), we faced session management issue with our deployment in VPS. Same code works fine with Google App Engine, but in VPS deployment session variable is not maintained. Our assumption is App engine is generating a custom cookie / session varilable which is not available in VPS.

Is  there any alternative option in Google app engine which we can use.

Would appreciate any help in sorting out this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

GAE Standard *can* use HTTPS. See the `secure` setting in the `app.yaml`. Reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref).

Besides this, you can run the webhook backend anywhere you want. You can run this on a non-cloud machine as long as it's exposed to the internet and can handle HTTPS traffic. There's [tons of guides](https://www.google.com/search?q=run%20https%20server) on how to enable SSL on whatever you use.

The webhook must simply adhere to the requirements [listed here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook#requirements).

As far as GCP services that can be used (off the top of my head, I might be missing one or two):

- Compute Engine
- GAE (Flex/STD)
- Cloud Run
- k8s
- Cloud Functions

Comment: Thank you Edo. We tried deploying the flask app in Hostinger VPS(with SSL configuration,Flask+gunicorn+nginx), we didnt face any issues with our dialogflow bot integrated with GA for a single user. When we tried with more than one user, session values are overwritten. Since we are developing this product for a charity purpose, we are not able to afford much for backend deployment. We tried heroku and pythonanywhere. We faced the same issue. we didnt face this issue in Google app engine. Is there any setting needs to be done for deployment in non-cloud environment to handle multi-user sessions.

Comment: So you are not managing the sessions properly. A session should not be shared between different users. I recommend looking into how sessions are handled for the version of dialogflow you are using (se/cx). FE [this](https://github.com/googleapis/python-dialogflow/tree/main/samples/snippets) shows a session ID. You need to use this to separate different users. Use this in combination with Flask [sessions](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) so your server knows which user it's "talking" to... **NOTE** Flask sessions and dialogflow sessions are two different things...